# Understanding representations of the symmetric group in terms of matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, representation-theory

I'm a newbie in group theory and I can't understand linear representations of the symmetric group. Could you please expain it to me with such an example?

Let $n=5$. So, we have the symmetric group $S_5$.
What does the linear representation of this group corresponding to the Young diagram (3,2) look like?
As I can understand, the dimension of this representation is ${5\choose 3}=10$.
What are the invertible matrices that form this representation? How to get them, to generate them?

Answer (score 1):

A Young diagram corresponds to a Young subgroup. (3,2) inside 5 corresponds to $\def\Sym{\operatorname{Sym}}Y_{3,2}=\Sym(3)\times\Sym(2) \leq \Sym(5)$. These are the permutations that move the first three things amongst themselves and the last two things amongst themselves, but don't mix the three with the two.

$\Sym(5)$ acts on the cosets of $Y_{3,2}$ by permuting them. There are $\dfrac{5!}{3!2!} = 10$ of them, conveniently labelled as partitions:

- $P_1 = (\{1,2,3\},\{4,5\})$,
- $P_2 = (\{1,2,4\},\{3,5\})$,
- $P_3 = (\{1,2,5\},\{3,4\})$,
- $P_4 = (\{1,3,4\},\{2,5\})$,
- $P_5 = (\{1,3,5\},\{2,4\})$,
- $P_6 = (\{1,4,5\},\{2,3\})$,
- $P_7 = (\{2,3,4\},\{1,5\})$,
- $P_8 = (\{2,3,5\},\{1,4\})$,
- $P_9 = (\{2,4,5\},\{1,3\})$, and
- $P_{10} = (\{3,4,5\},\{1,2\})$

Each element of $\Sym(5)$ can be applied to these $P_i$ and will give some other $P_j$. The permutation representation for $(3,2)$ is that permutation of the labels of the $P_i,P_j$. For example the permutation that swaps 1 and 2 in the original action on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ will now swap $P_4$ with $P_7$, and $P_5$ with $P_8$, and $P_6$ with $P_9$, but leave $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$, $P_{10}$ alone. If you use Cauchy notation [2,1,3,4,5] maps to [1,2,3,7,8,9,4,5,6,10]. If you use cycle notation (1,2) maps to (4,7)(5,8)(6,9).

The matrix part is not a big step. The matrix corresponding to a permutation has entries defined by:
$$M_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } \sigma(i) = j \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

So [1,2,3,7,8,9,4,5,6,10] = (4,7)(5,8)(6,9) has matrix representation
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr|rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]$$
Here the lines indicate a hopefully helpful block structure this particular matrix has (basically the cycles of the cycle notation, but I've chosen my example so this picture is pretty, other permutations might not have nice places to put the lines).

This representation is not irreducible (it has invariant subspaces of dimensions 1, 4, and 5), but it has very nice matrix entries.

Comment: To piggy back off this a bit:  There is a natural linear map from the standard $5$ dimensional permutation representation into this where we send each $a \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to the sum of those set partitions where $a$ is in the part of size $2$.  So for example in the above notation $1$ would get sent to $P_7 + P_8 + P_9 +P_{10}$.  The irreducible Specht module $S^{(3,2)}$ is the orthogonal complement to the image of that map.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nontrivial question first solved by Alfred Young. You can find an account in lectures by Adriano Garsia which now appeared in book form

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030583729

For an (integer) partition $\lambda$ of $n$, a filling $T$ of the Young diagram of $\lambda$ with the numbers $1,\ldots,n$ where each appears exactly once, is called an injective Young tableau. For a permutation $\sigma$, we denote by $\sigma T$ the injective tableau obtained by replacing each entry $i$, by $\sigma(i)$. We let $R(T)$ denote the subgroup of permutations which permute entries within rows. We let $C(T)$ denote the subgroup of permutations which permute entries within columns.

For $T_1,T_2$ any two injective tableaux, let $C(T_1,T_2)={\rm sgn}(\beta_1)$ if there exists $\alpha_1\in R(T_1)$ and $\beta_1\in C(T_1)$ such that $T_2=\alpha_1\beta_1 T_1$, otherwise let $C(T_1,T_2)=0$.

Let $M^{\lambda}(\sigma)$ be the matrix with rows and columns indexed by standard tableaux of shape $\lambda$ and entries
$$
M^{\lambda}(\sigma)_{T_1,T_2}=C(T_1,\sigma T_2)\ .
$$

Finally, let $R^{\lambda}(\sigma)=(M^{\lambda}({\rm Id}))^{-1}M^{\lambda}(\sigma)$.
Then $\sigma\mapsto R^{\lambda}(\sigma)$ is an explicit matrix expression for the irreducible representation indexed by the partition $\lambda$.